# Difference between Markdown and Haml?

Tags: haml, markdown, difference

I am a web designer trying to improve... These last few days I had decided to study [Haml](http://haml.info/) and SCSS and other things, but I just discovered [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) and now I don't understand the difference between Markdown and Haml. Do they serve the same purpose? Which of the two is better? I've read they can be combined... Maybe should I learn both tools?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Markdown**

From Markdown's [syntax page](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

> Markdown’s syntax is intended for one purpose: to be used as a format
>   for writing for the web.
>
> Markdown is not a replacement for HTML, or even close to it. ...

It is useful for writing purposes only. A fitting example is Stackoverflow. You can easily format your questions to include some basics such as a list, a header or a quote.

**HAML**

[HAML](http://haml.info/) on the other hand is used for developing websites. It provides everything HTML does in a cleaner way. This includes all HTML attributes (such as ID's & classes) and embedded Ruby code. They have a great [tutorial](http://haml.info/tutorial.html) to get a brief overview.

My experience with HAML has been great. It's clearer and simpler to use than normal HTML. I'd definitely give it a try ;)

Comment: Now I understand! So I'll give _Haml_ a try.
**Thank you** very much.